# Action of a massive spin-2 field

Tags: gravity, lagrangian-formalism, group-theory, representation-theory, trace

I'm reading about gravitational waves at the moment (mainly using Maggiore's textbook). In it he gives the Pauli-Fierz action for a massive spin-2 field and the action contains the trace of the field. However, Maggiore argues that the irreps of the Lorentz group are either symmetric traceless tensors, or antisymmetric tensors. He then further decomposes these by looking only at the $SO(3)$ group and for rank two tensors, only in the symmetric traceless tensors do we get an irrep of spin-2 fields.
So, if we know that the irrep of a spin-2 field must be symmetric and traceless, why do we put the trace in to the action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracelessness condition $h=0$ emerges from the action as a constraint. If one imposes that condition on the action prior to varying it (without modifying anything else) than it would be another theory, with a different number of degrees of freedom. More specifically this *modified* theory would contain a scalar *ghost* field  (a field with the wrong sign in front of the kinetic energy term of the action). Only when the coefficients in front of $h^{\mu\nu}h_{\mu\nu}$ and $h^2$ terms differ by a sign only (Fierz–Pauli tuning), and when the terms with derivatives would coincide with the linearization of Einstein–Hilbert action, the theory would be free of ghosts.

For a general analysis see:

- van Nieuwenhuizen, P. (1973). *On ghost-free tensor Lagrangians and linearized gravitation*. Nuclear Physics B, 60, 478-492, [doi:10.1016/0550-3213(73)90194-6](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(73)90194-6).

Comment: I'm not sure if you've seen Maggiore's reasoning, but I don't see why we need h=0 to emerge from the action. Yes, it falls out of the equations of motion, but it looks like we can arrive at the same conclusion just by a group theoretical argument that the field needs to be a spin-2 field therefore must be traceless and symmetric. So I don't understand why this group theory argument isn't enough? What's the point in looking at the group theory behind it if we don't use any of its results?

Comment: Yes, you can arrive to a conclusion by different routes, you are welcome to take your own. But the derivation of FP action does uses group theory arguments: it is the only possible action describing a massive spin-2 field, putting other Lorentz-invariant terms (and/or altering coefficient on existing) would also introduce spin-1 or spin-0 degrees of freedom. And action itself is not the end of story, it is used as a starting point to introducing sources/interaction, writing propagator, Feynman rules etc.